# Multiple `.sublime-settings` files for single syntax

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext

For example, I want 2 separate preference files for Markdown syntax.

This will work:

```
Markdown.sublime-settings
```

This will not:

```
Markdown_Additional_Settings.sublime-settings
```

When I open some `.md`-file, I want settings from both these preference files to be applied. In other words, these settings should me merged.

Is there some trick to make it work?

Comment: Sublime selects the syntax specific settings by looking for a settings file with the same name as the syntax that the file is for (e.g. `Markdown`) so there is no out of the box way to apply settings from multiple files in this case without using a plugin to pull in extra settings.

Comment: If your use case is something like having only certain markdown files have extra settings, something like this plugin may be of help in this case: https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Project%20Specific%20Syntax%20Settings

Comment: Oh, thanks, I will look it today.

Comment: If I am not mistaken you can just add a subfolder to your Packages folder *Preferences > Browse Packages...*) and put the settings file there. So you have on settings file in `Packages/User/Markdown.sublime-settings` and one in `Packages/AdditionalSettings/Markdown.sublime-settings`. These should be merged and the setting in the User folder should be should if they both define the same setting.

Comment: @r-stein Hm, I tested it, seems it is true. To be honest, I'm feeling myself a bit dumb. If you repost it as answer, I will accept it. And by the way, we are not forced to use User folder. It also works for `Packages\MyMainSettings\Markdown.sublime-settings` and `Packages\MyAdditionalSettings\Markdown.sublime-settings`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just create the settings file `Markdown.sublime-settings` twice in different subfolders of `Packages` (*Preferences > Browse Packages...*). Usually you would create your main settings inside the User folder, because it has the highest precedence. So you create the files `Packages/MyAdditionalSettings/Markdown-sublime-settings` and `Packages/User/Markdown.sublime-settings` or `Packages/MyMainSettings/Markdown.sublime-settings`. If you use the same setting in both files the one in the User folder or in the folder, which is the last in the lexical order, will be used.